# Compare between multiple Rails I18n YAML files to get them matching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

We have multiple I18n language files with thousands of lines in english, french and test language(x)..

Is there an online parser that is able to match them up much easier than going line by line? Lots of translations are missing between files + some are not at the same spots..

It would save me a lot of time :)

This is for Rails I18n

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `i18n-tasks` gem? I think it may do exactly what you need.

https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the gem `i18n_yaml_sorter`, which is designed to solve this specific problem.

https://github.com/redealumni/i18n_yaml_sorter